# Electric hot water system water stops running

Tags: valve, hot-water, shutoff

Hot water is running fine then a clunk sound is heard and the water flow stops on all house hot water taps. What could be the cause? I suspect of the shut off valve on the boiler, could that be the case?

Comment: Probably where it happens, but suspect a blob of sediment or something is entering the pipe/valve when using the hot water.  Valve is okay, but gets block.

Comment: Check antiscald valve